# Get the model of a partial view and use it in an action link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, partial-views, actionlink

Let's say that I have this view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Send Items";
}

<h2>Sent Items</h2>

<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        Html.RenderAction("AdvancedSearchEngine", "PartialViews");
    }

    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Selection", "MenuSelection")
</p>
```

I want to add an html `ActionLink` that will get me to another view. I want to get all the model used in the partial view in this actionlink to create the list of items that will be displayed in this view.

Something like `@Html.ActionLink("See the results", "DisplayItems", new {_myObject = "blablabla"})`.

Is there any way to do that?

**EDIT**

I have added this method:

`@Html.ActionLink("See the results", "DisplayItems", "DispatchItems", new { model = Model }, null);`

But once the method actually hits, the object is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new action in your controller:

```
public ActionResult DisplayItems(MyModel model)
{
   // Do stuff
   return View(model);
}
```

Then use this AcitonLink in the SendItems view:

```
Html.ActionLink("See the results", "DisplayItems", "ControllerName", new { model = Model }, null);
```

Comment: That makes sense, however when I hit the action in the controller the model is not carried over.

Comment: Are you sure you passed it and the name of the property in the anonymous type is the same as the parameter name?

Comment: Can you add your action `DisplayItems` too? Also, try adding a breakpoint on the line where you call `ActionLink` and check if the `Model` in your view contains what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood completely this problem but lets try.
Use AjaxHelper to do this, makes more sense, and render a partial view. The ActionLink must have some information about the model that you want to show, can be an id or anything else. Then you can render this by clicking the link and without a full page refresh. Don't forget to include JQuery reference at the main view.

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Send Items";
  }

  <h2>Sent Items</h2>

  <p>
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
      Html.RenderAction("AdvancedSearchEngine", "PartialViews");
  }

   @Ajax.ActionLink("Back to Selection", "MenuSelection", new {id = Model.Id}
             new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod ="GET", 
             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
             UpdateTargetId = "results")
```

```
 <div id="results"></div>

 public ActionResult DisplayItems(int id)
 {
     // Do stuff
     return PartialView("");
 }
```

Hopes this help you!